# do clients running .net applications that reference the excel API need to have excel installed?

Tags: c#, .net, excel, com

To be more specific, I'm referring to the COM component Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll.

If clients don't have excel installed on their computer, would the .net application even run or just crash the moment there is an attempt to access the dll?

Also, is it possible to work around any possible limitations by deploying a copy of this dll along with the .net application? (Assuming that it's legal to do so.)

Comment: Pretty sure the answer to this is "yes, they will need Excel"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're usig Excel COM Wrappers and you call any of the functions therein, you must have Excel installed in that computer. The interop DLLs just call the COM servers exposed by Office, in fact most surely in your computer if you test this you'll see an EXCEL.EXE process in the Task Manager.

So yeah, you need Excel installed for interop to work.