# should my clients to have installed Excel if my app use Excel.DLL

Tags: c#, wpf, excel, import

Should my client to install MS Excell on their PC, if my application use Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll to import data from EXCEL file?
Or is enough only my app. to have this reference.

Thank you.

Comment: Your clients need to have Excel (and the VSTO extension) installed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [do clients running .net applications that reference the excel API need to have excel installed?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14729861/do-clients-running-net-applications-that-reference-the-excel-api-need-to-have-e)

Comment: you should use the Office Open XML library as that has no direct dependency on Office https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb448854.aspx

Comment: Use Open Xml Library or the much simpler dll [ClosedXml](https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML)

Answer (score 0):

If your client does not have excel installed and your app reads sheets you must install the assembly.
[Excel DLL](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3508)

Comment: I haven't tested it, but I think this could also be achieved by using a [NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel/)

Comment: @meica Those are just the references the OP already uses. The package just enables you to *build* a project without having MS Office installed - it will not help you *run* an application that uses Office.InterOp.